# How can I preserve the viewstate of a partial view when the server side validation failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

These are steps to reproduce my problem:

```
The user opens a partial view.
The user does not select the correct item in the DropDownList.
The user sends the form to the server.
The form is shown with the validation error.
```

Thats good so far.

What bothers me is that the previously selected item by the user is reset.
That means the first item in the DropDownList is again the pre-selected/default value.

How can I change that?

**UPDATE**

When the web server returns the response to the client:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(form).attr('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
        debugger;
        if (response.success) {
            dlg.dialog("close");
        }
        else { dlg.html(response); } // In this response the selected item has the correct selected=selected attribute
    }
});
```

the dialog shows the response html via dlg.html(response)

What I found out is that the selected item in the returned html is correct:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#selectUnitType').ddslick({
            showSelectedHTML: false,
            onSelected: function (data) {
            }
        });

        var node = $('#TreeDiv').dynatree("getActiveNode");        
        var selectedParentUnitId = node.data.key;
        var templateId = $('input[name=TemplateId]').val();

        $('form input[name=IsParentFolder]').val(node.data.isFolder);
        $('form input[name=TemplateId]').val(templateId);
        $('form input[name=ParentId]').val(selectedParentUnitId);
    });
</script>

<form action="/Unit/CreateChildren?_=1358449701481" method="post"> 
    <select 
    class="input-validation-error"
     data-val="true" 
     data-val-number="The field Selected unit type must be a number." 
     data-val-required="&#39;Selected Folder Type Id&#39; darf keinen Null-Wert aufweisen." 
     id="selectUnitType"
     name="SelectedFolderTypeId">
        <option data-description="Contains other folders" data-imagesrc="../Content/Images/de.png" value="0">Folder</option>
        <option data-description="Contains teststeps" data-imagesrc="../Content/Images/gb.png" selected="selected" value="1">Teststep</option>
    </select>
</form>

[FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(CreateUnitViewModelValidator))]
public class CreateUnitViewModel
{
    public CreateUnitViewModel()
    {
        List<ImageSelectListItem> items = new List<ImageSelectListItem>();
        items.Add(new ImageSelectListItem { Description = "Contains other folders", Value = ((int)UnitType.Folder).ToString() , Text = "Folder", ImageFileName = "de.png", Selected = false });
        items.Add(new ImageSelectListItem { Description = "Contains teststeps", Value = ((int)UnitType.Teststeps).ToString() , Text = "Teststep", ImageFileName = "gb.png", Selected = false });
        DisplayList = items;
    }

    [Remote("UnitExists", "Unit", ErrorMessage = "This name already exists.", AdditionalFields = "TemplateId")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }
    public int TemplateId { get; set; } 
    [DisplayName("Selected unit type")]
    public int SelectedFolderTypeId { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public bool IsParentFolder { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ImageSelectListItem> DisplayList { get; set; }
} 



[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateChildren()
{   
    return PartialView(new CreateUnitViewModel());
}




[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateChildren(CreateUnitViewModel unitViewModel)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid && !_unitService.UnitExists(unitViewModel.Name, unitViewModel.TemplateId))
{
    Unit unit = Mapper.Map<CreateUnitViewModel, Unit>(unitViewModel);
    _unitService.CreateChild(unit);
    UnitTreeViewModel unitTreeViewModel = Mapper.Map<Unit, UnitTreeViewModel>(unit);
    return new JsonNetResult(new { success = true, unit = unitTreeViewModel });
}
ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "This name already exists.");
return PartialView(unitViewModel);
}
```

Is the problem the Constructor code of the Create viewmodel? The html seems correct why then can the rest play any role? What is rendered to the client counts...

Comment: you need to provide some page code here please

Comment: @AndrasZoltan I will do when I am at home :)

Comment: show us your Post ActionResult

Comment: DONE Darin I was one minute after you ;-)

Comment: I am using this plugin: http://ddslickremablized.remabledesigns.com/ Anyone sees the failure or should I contact the author because there is a bug?

Comment: OK I have debugged the ddslick javascript code when the html is returned. There seems to be a bug because the some condition is not true always the index zero is taken for the default value. I will pm the author and try to fix it in the meantime :P

Comment: A last evidence was to remove the ddslick to have the default dropdown and indeed my selected is considered when the server sends the response html. Oh my...